# Parsing "Happiness makes up in height for what it lacks in length"

Tags: syntax, parsing

This is the title of a [Robert Frost poem](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/5964894-happiness-makes-up-in-height-for-what-it-lacks-in):

> Happiness makes up in height for what it lacks in length.

I am having difficulties in understanding the correct interpretation.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Comment: Also, can you give more details on what parts you are having a problem with, or what interpretations have occurred to you, please?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/5964894-happiness-makes-up-in-height-for-what-it-lacks-in

Comment: @DavidSiegel    this is the link.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to interpret a "one-off" figurative usage in a poem.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a standard or common metaphor.  The job of poets is to invent new original language ideas

The idea here is probably  "Length = how long something lasts in time" and "Height = how important or effective something is at a particular time"

Happiness doesn't last a long time, but is "big and important" when you are happy.